# Is there a chance for divine forces to get into common man's body and make do things?

Tags: belief

Is there a chance for divine forces to get into common man's body and make do extraordinary things?

Comment: As a human being everyone is a common man so if you refer to the past avatars they all were divine beings/forces within a common man doing extra-ordinary acts.

Comment: I heard and seen too when Goddess entered in body of a lady during Jagaran or other spiritual occasion. Don't know how to put these but I have no idea whether it was for real or something else.